# Play 2.0 Captcha

Tags: playframework-2.0

There is a Captcha API in 1.2.x.  However, I cannot find it in 2.0.

Is there an API for Captcha in Play 2.0?  If it is not provided, anyone has any substitutes?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for Captcha that I'm aware of. A good alternative is [Recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha). Widely used, you may easily find help online about it, and quite good at what it does.